# Unexpected result by sqrt() in quadratic formula using <math.h>

Tags: c++, class, pass-by-reference

This is the task i was given

Your task is to create a class named equation which will have the data members a, b and c which are the coefficients
of the quadratic equation. The class will have two more data members namely proot and nroot which stand for the
positive root and negative root of the equation. Suppose that variables a, b and c are integers. Where proot and nroot
are floats.
- Construct the class objects by using a nullary constructor.
- Then design a friend function which will determine the proot and nroot of the equation.
- Create another friend function which will display the values of proot and nroot.

I have a couple of questions

- I tried to declare "a" as an integer and take its square root it was giving an error saying that "More than one instances of sqrt match the argument list". Same thing worked when i declared "a" as double and type-casted into integer. Why is is so?
- the output should be 
  -1
  -1.5
  but my output is entirely different. What am i doing Wrong?
- My professor told me that to make a function friend of a class we have to write its prototype in the class. Prototype does not include "&" but if i dont write it the program does not work

enter code here

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
class Equation 
{    
    friend void Roots (Equation & );
    friend void Display (Equation &);
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    float proot;
    float nroot;
public:
    Equation ()
    {
        a=0;
        b=0;
        c=0;
        proot=0;
        nroot=0;
    }
    Equation (int _a, int _b, int _c)
    {
        a=_a;
        b=_b;
        c=_c;
    }

};
void Roots (Equation &obj1)
{
    double a;
    int determinant;
    a=(obj1.b^2)-(4*obj1.a * obj1.c);
    if (a>-1)
        determinant=int(sqrt(a));
    else
    {
        cout<<"Determinant returns an imaginary number; solution not possible\n";
        exit (0);
    }
    obj1.proot= (-obj1.b + determinant)/2*obj1.a;
    obj1.nroot= (-obj1.b - determinant)/2*obj1.a;
}
void Display (Equation &obj1)
{    
    cout<<"Value of positive root : "<<obj1.proot<<endl;
    cout<<"Value of negative root : "<<obj1.nroot<<endl;
}
void main ()
{
    int a,b,c;
    cout<<"Calculate Quadratic Equation"<<endl<<"Enter A : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter B : ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter C  ";
    cin>>c;
    Equation obj(a,b,c);
    Display (obj);
    Display (obj);

}
```

Comment: `^` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: produces very long number -1.07374 + 008 in both cases

Comment: `Display` and `Roots` should really be named `DisplayRoots` and `CalculateRoots`, and should be member functions of `Equation`.

Comment: Yes i know that but since we are learning use of friend fuctions, we have to do it like this!

Comment: Also, your code doesn't even compile on my machine because you have `void main()`. The main function is required to return `int`.

Comment: Does not affect the answer unfortunately

Comment: If you are going to use friend functions, at least make your display function useful and make it an overload of `ostream::operator<<`.  If the professor is requiring a friend function to calculate the roots, make the "real" calculate function a class member that is private, and call it from the "friend" calculate function.  At least then you have a piece of a halfway decent design. :)

Comment: @ZacHowland I would do that but i am supposed to do it this way... that is why i posted the Problem Statement above

Comment: @UsamaKhurshid What I suggested in no way violates the parameters for the assignment.  I'll demonstrate in an answer.

Comment: Also as an algebra note, the number you calculate from the equation there is called a discriminant, not determinant. A determinant is something else entirely, from matrix algebra.

Comment: @user1264727 Actually the discriminant is the determinant of the associated quadratic form, so it is very much related ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a=(obj1.b^2)-(4*obj1.a * obj1.c);
```

The `^` operator in C++ is a bitwise XOR, so `obj1.b^2` part calculates the XOR of `obj1.b` and the bit pattern `000...10`. That is definitely not what you want here.

The [power function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) in C++ is `pow`, so you square that by doing `pow(obj1.b, 2)`, also if you're working with C++ it would be better to include the header as `cmath` and not `math.h`.

EDIT: You also never call `Roots()` to calculate anything:

```
Equation obj(a,b,c);
Display (obj);
```

Here you construct your equation and immediately try to show its result, without first calling `Roots(obj)`. That will at least calculate an answer but is still wrong because there seems to be a mistake in your calculation.

You also need parenthesis around `2 * obj1.a` in your calculation. Try with and without them and see the difference!

```
Calculate Quadratic Equation
Enter A : 10
Enter B : 10
Enter C  2
Value of positive root : -0.276393
Value of negative root : -0.723607
```

And this [is correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10x%5E2%20%2b%2010x%20%2b%202%20==%200,%20solve%20for%20x). Although you apparently expect the two roots to have different signs, that is not necessarily going to be the case.

Comment: even if i use (obj1.b*obj1.b) istead of obj1.b^2 is still gives same output

Comment: @UsamaKhurshid Editing answer, you never actually calculate the roots - your Roots function isn't called. You construct the equation and then try to display the result without calculating anything.

Comment: yes, my bad. that line didnt get copied from my compiler. still producing wrong result!

Comment: You did not put parenthesis around `2*obj1.a` in your calculation. Put parenthesis and you get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
obj1.b^2
```

try

```
pow(obj1.b, 2)
```

^ is doing a XOR operation - probably not what you had in mind.

You also never seem to call your Roots function. You need something like:

```
Equation obj(a,b,c);
Roots(obj);
Display (obj);
```

You are getting big numbers returned, because when you call the Equation (int _a, int _b, int _c) constructor, proot and nroot are left uninitialized. You are then returning them at the end, because you never call the Roots function.

Comment: even if i use (obj1.b*obj1.b) istead of obj1.b^2 is still gives same output

Comment: Note the edit I've made above - you don't seem to have a call to the Roots function anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

As an example of how to create useful friend functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class Equation 
{   
public:
    Equation () : m_a(0), m_b(0), m_c(0), m_proot(0), m_nroot(0) 
    {
    }

    Equation (int a, int b, int c) : m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c), m_proot(0, false), m_nroot(0, false)
    {
    }

private: 
    // these would be better as floats or doubles, but your requirement appears to want them to be ints.  You'll need to cast them when doing division operations.
    int m_a;
    int m_b;
    int m_c;
    // std::optional would be more useful, but it was removed from the last C++14 draft
    std::pair<float, bool> m_proot;
    std::pair<float, bool> m_nroot;

    void Calculate()
    {
        // do your actual calculations here
        // note that you will need to set the m_proot.second and m_nroot.second values to true if they are valid
        // also note that ^ is not a power operation; you need to use std::pow for that
    }

    // this friend function is useful
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Equation&);
    // this one is created just to meet the requirements of the assignment
    friend void CalculateRoots(Equation&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Equation& e)
{
    std::cout << "Roots of (" << e.m_a << ")x^2 + (" << e.m_b << ")x + " << e.m_c << ": "
    if (m_nroot.second || m_proot.second)
    {
        std::cout << "(";
        if (m_nroot.second)
        {
            std::cout << m_nroot.first << ", ";
        }

        if (m_proot.second)
        {
            std::cout << m_proot.first;
        }
        std::cout << ")" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No real roots" << std::endl;
    }
    return os;
}

// must be friend function to call private member function Calculate
void CalculateRoots(Equation &obj1)
{
    obj1.Calculate();
}

// does not need to be a friend function - using operator<< overload (which is a friend function itself)
void DisplayRoots(Equation &obj1)
{    
    std::cout << obj1;
}

int main ()
{
    int a,b,c;
    cout<<"Calculate Quadratic Equation"<<endl<<"Enter A : ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter B : ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter C  ";
    cin>>c;
    Equation obj(a,b,c);
    CalculateRoots(obj);
    DisplayRoots(obj);
}
```

This gives you the required friend functions from the assignment's description while at least pushing you closer to a better design.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys so i changed the data type of variables from

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

to

```
float a;
float b;
float c;
```

because it was giving warning about conversions and data loss and also changed the statement where proot and nroot are calculated from

```
 obj1.proot= (-obj1.b + determinant)/2*obj1.a;
obj1.nroot= (-obj1.b - determinant)/2*obj1.a;
```

to

```
 obj1.proot= (-obj1.b + determinant)/(2*obj1.a);
obj1.nroot= (-obj1.b - determinant)/(2*obj1.a);
```

Now it is working as expected...Producing correct reusult! :)